# Biblatex-abnt: Year suffix not showing in same author

Tags: biblatex

How to make the suffix in the year appear when it is the same year for the same author in the references? It works in the citations:

> (AUTHOR, 2001a; 2001b)

but not in the references:

> [...], 2001.
>
> [...], 2001.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=abnt,
    ittitles
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @book{book1,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title 1},
  publisher = {Publisher},
 },
 @book{book2,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title 2},
  publisher = {Publisher},
 },
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{book1,book2}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was happening. The style I am using (abnt) did not have this feature because the norms of ABNT do not use it. I wrote to the person responsible for the style and he has added this option. Now, if someone want to use suffixes in the references too, he has to use the option `extrayear`.

(The files are not in CTAN yet, but one can download and install them from [Github](https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt))